# Как правильно написать массив?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать вот такого рода массив? Выдает ошибку синтаксиса.

```
y1 = ([1 if (y1[0] > 0.0 and y1[1] > y1[2] and y1[4] > y1[2]) or 0 if (y1[0] < 0.0 and y1[1] < y1[2] and y1[4] < y1[2]) else NaN for y1 in y1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное вместо:

```
or 0 if
```

Имелось в виду:

```
else 0 if
```

Тернарный оператор `if` выглядит так:

```
x if condition else y
```

В вашем случае это два тернарных оператора:

```
x if condition1 else y if condition2 else z
```

P.S. Хотя тут у вас всё-равно непонятно что, переменная итерации должна иметь другое название, чем коллекция, по которой вы итерируетесь:

```
for y1 in y1
```

Но это уже другая проблема.

Comment: О! Точно! Благодарю!

Comment: @Xray321 У вас там с `for` ещё проблема, но уже не синтаксическая )

Comment: Да, есть такое ) буду решать, просто учусь, вот и провожу эксперименты )
Но, если подскажете, то будет здорово!

Comment: @Xray321 Тут уже без знания задачи пока больше нечего подсказать )

Comment: Понял. В любом случае, спасибо огромное! Буду дальше разбираться )